# How to take over all values from one widget to another in Kivy automatically?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently working on an App with Kivy where a new Tab shall be added when the second tab (id: secondtab) is clicked. This is happening successfully via the addtab(self) method, but the new tab shall be looking exactly like the second one. As everything is written in the kv file, the method shall take the values from the kv file. Unfortunately, being also not so into kivy yet, I have no real idea how I could implement this. I tried it with self.ids, but how do I chose all the values?

Ultimately, how do i inherit/overtake all the values and layout from the second to the third tab?

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelItem

class kvfile(TabbedPanel):

    def addtab(self):
        self.add_widget(TabbedPanelItem())

class AddTabApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kvfile()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AddTabApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<kvfile>:
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'General Infos'
        text_size: self.width, self.height
        ScrollView:
            StackLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                padding: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                spacing: [10, 10]
                Label:
                    height: 80
                    size_hint: [1, None]
                    text: 'General entries'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: secondtab
        text: 'Code: ' + text1.text
        text_size: self.width, self.height
        on_press: 
            root.addtab()
        ScrollView:
            StackLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                padding: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                spacing: [10, 10]
                BoxLayout:
                    height: 60
                    size_hint: [1, None]
                    spacing: 10
                    Label:
                        id: label1
                        height: 50
                        size_hint: [1, None]
                        text: 'Code:'
                    TextInput:
                        id: text1
                        height: 50
                        size_hint: [1, None]
                        text: 'Add Code'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question fully.
Where you have the textinput I would recommend just writing it to a variable

like:

```
string = self.ids.text1.text
```

and from that point I would then just reassign to the textbox on tab 2 
like:

```
self.ids.text2.text = string
```

of course the first tab will need an on_leave: function that passes the textinput to the variable and the second tab will need an on_enter: function to write to the textinput

let me know if this  isnt clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! So I am not sure if this would solve my problem and my post was not too clear I guess. When the new tab is created by clicking on the second one, it shall look exactly like the second tab, so take over every label, textinput, button, StackLayout, ScrollView etc. And I will have way more widgets in the actual tab so I don't know if it is handy to create variables for all of them.